# Error when trying to install Rmpfr in R related to the header file mpfr.h

Tags: r, package

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I have R version 3.1.2. When I am trying to install the `Rmpfr` package, I get this error

```
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
```

I am new to Linux, so I don't know exactly how to fix this.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev`

Comment: the package couldn't be located

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/libmpfr-dev

Comment: this works @Pascal can you write as a proper answer so that can be marked as working?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should install libmpfr-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

(answer from the first, highly upvoted comment by @user3710546)

Comment: thanks, installed, `sudo apt install *libm*pfr* -y`~

Answer (score 4):

If using Amazon Linux, CentOS, or anything else that comes bundled with yum, do this:

> sudo yum install mpfr-devel